# How to create api in wso2am by payload

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I deployed wso2am-4.0 on my vm, I tried to create api by curl. I'm so confused I don't know how to add params in paylod. I guess that params could be added to payload in operations section. but there are no attribute about params. How to add body or query params in payload?

```
{
"name": "PizzaShackAPI",
"description": "This is a simple API for Pizza Shack online pizza delivery store.",
"context": "pizza",
"version": "1.0.0",
"provider": "admin",
"lifeCycleStatus": "CREATED",
"responseCachingEnabled": false,
"hasThumbnail": false,
"isDefaultVersion": false,
"enableSchemaValidation": false,
"type": "HTTP",
"transport": [
  "http",
  "https"
],
"tags": [
  "substract",
  "add"
],
"policies": [
  "Unlimited"
],
"apiThrottlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
"securityScheme": ["oauth2"],
"maxTps": {
  "production": 1000,
  "sandbox": 1000
},
"visibility": "PUBLIC",
"visibleRoles": [],
"visibleTenants": [],
"subscriptionAvailability": "CURRENT_TENANT",
"additionalProperties": [
  {
      "name" : "AdditionalProperty",
      "value" : "PropertyValue",
      "display" : true 
  }
],
"accessControl": "NONE",
"businessInformation": {
  "businessOwner": "John Doe",
  "businessOwnerEmail": "johndoe@wso2.com",
  "technicalOwner": "Jane Roe",
  "technicalOwnerEmail": "janeroe@wso2.com"
},
"endpointConfig": {
  "endpoint_type": "http",
  "sandbox_endpoints": {
    "url": "https://localhost:9443/am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api/"
  },
  "production_endpoints": {
    "url": "https://localhost:9443/am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api/"
  }
},
"operations": [
  {
    "target": "/order/{orderId}",
    "verb": "POST",
    "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited"
    "uriMapping": "uriMapping-test1",
    "payloadSchema": "payloadSchema-test1"
  },
  {
    "target": "/menu",
    "verb": "GET",
    "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
    "uriMapping": "uriMapping-test2",
    "payloadSchema": "payloadSchema-test1"
    
  }
]
```

}

In ui, there would be added like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to do a Swagger PUT - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v2/publisher-v2/#tag/APIs/operation/getAPISwagger

The API payload does not support adding these Swagger specific stuff.

Here is a sample definition for the resource check - https://gist.github.com/pubudu538/8a8eec6663cc0bbf97302bf50a7f2194#file-swagger-put-L354